# which plugin or pre-installation are need to dockerize build on jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

which plugin or pre-installation are need to dockerize build on jenkins?
I keep having this stupid stack !

```
WorkflowScript: 74: Expected a symbol @ line 74, column 15.
             docker.image('maven:3.3.3-jdk-8').inside("-v  $PWD:/data")     {
             ^

WorkflowScript: 74: "error" should have 1 arguments but has 2 arguments     instead. @ line 74, column 15.
             docker.image('maven:3.3.3-jdk-8').inside("-v  $PWD:/data") {
```

Edit : I have the docker pipeline plugin installed

the full jenkinsfile

```
stage('docker') {
       steps {
          checkout scm
          docker.image('maven:3.3.3-jdk-8').inside("-v  $PWD:/data") {
            writeFile file: 'settings.xml', text: "<settings><localRepository>${pwd()}/.m2repo</localRepository></settings>"
            sh 'mvn clean install'

          }
 }
```

Comment: did you install this plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Pipeline+Plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see a similar error in [issue JENKINS-44749](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44749)

> It seems the problem is deeper than I though since the Docker Pipeline Plugin also fails but with the following message:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 46: Expected a symbol @ line 46, column 25.
docker.image(‘node:7-alpine’).inside {
```

> After reinstalling all plugins and updating Jenkins to 2.64 the original error is gone but I still get the error from the above comment.
>   **Wrapping `docker.image` in a `script` block makes it work, but it wasn't needed before**.

```
        steps {
            script {
                docker.image('maven:3.3.3-jdk-8').inside("-v  $PWD:/data") {
                    writeFile file: 'settings.xml', text: "<settings><localRepository>${pwd()}/.m2repo</localRepository></settings>"
                    sh 'mvn clean install'
                } 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello, your solution correct my issue, but it still don't work: The mvn clean install append not in a container, but in my working directory. Any idea why?

Comment: @sab Looks a bit like https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33510. Possible workaround: using `withDockerContainer`, as in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46636

Comment: @sab Wait: I did mention the script step way before Larry wrote his answer... what is going on here?

Comment: 1)Sorry, I did'nt check the answer time, I correct It.
2) I will try the withDockerContainer

Answer (score 5):

Mostly scripted/declarative pipeline are mixed.

`docker.image` is scripted pipeline, see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/, therefore it needs to be wrapped with `script {}` inside declarative pipeline.

Here are two working sample, with jenkins slave `dockerserver`

Scripted pipeline

```
node("dockerserver") {
    stage('docker') {
        docker.image('maven:3.3.3-jdk-8').inside("-v  $PWD:/data") {
            writeFile file: 'settings.xml', text: "${pwd()}/.m2repo"
            sh 'ls'
        }
    }
}
```

Declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "dockerserver" }
    stages {
        stage('docker') {
            steps {
                script {    
                    docker.image('maven:3.3.3-jdk-8').inside("-v  $PWD:/data") {
                        writeFile file: 'settings.xml', text: "${pwd()}/.m2repo"
                        sh 'ls'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, what's the use of the agent here?  docker is installed on my jenkins container, but I don't use slave, do I need to?

Comment: Hy, sorry, but I did'nt pay attention to the time the answer was post, And the one bellow you answer had been post before. So I will mark the other response as the answer of this question.

Comment: no problem. I just want to give more complete info and the route cause to make it more clear to you